# Publish a SBT plugin exposing librairies in Scala 2.13

Tags: scala, sbt, scalatest, sbt-plugin

I order to publish JGiven reports using my Scalatests, in currently use https://github.com/seblm/sbt-jgiven-scalatest-reporter. 
This SBT plugin uses the Scalatest library to implement a flag enabling custom test reports in JSON.

Now I would like to upgrade my project to Scala 2.13.2. When I try to do this, the following error is displayed :

```
[error] Modules were resolved with conflicting cross-version suffixes in ProjectRef(uri("file:/Users/nurbela/Dev/project-2.13/"), "domain"):
[error]    org.scalatest:scalatest _2.13, _2.12
[error]    org.scala-lang.modules:scala-xml _2.13, _2.12
[error]    org.scalactic:scalactic _2.13, _2.12
```

(transitive dependency to `org.scalatest:scalatest_2.12`)

Unfortunately it seems that SBT plugins does not support librairies in 2.13.

How can I still use it, or keep the same level of functionality ?

Thanks in advance,